# Extracting prisoner from pedestrian area of city with out getting them shot

Tags: internal-consistency

Our intrepid detective has managed to capture a reasonably high ranking operative from the "Big Bad Organisation". He was captured in an area of the city built in such a way a car can not be brought in to transport the prisoner. Think close buildings, apartments with balconies, lots of people in the public areas.

Previously "Big Bad Organisation" has killed operatives who have been captured. The detective needs to get the prisoner back to the police station with out getting him killed. The prisoner would prefer to live. He won't kill him self, he is loyal but not that loyal. If he can escape he will however.

Assume near future levels of technology, guns and knives are the usual tools of "Big Bad Organisation". They are not going to blow up buildings. If they make a hit they prefer not to take out any police or bystanders, just the target. Killing police brings bigger investigations which they would prefer to avoid. The police have had to do this sort of thing a few times before and have training and equipment to make it easer.

The solution I have come up with is a kind of armoured box on a segway thing to put the prisoner in. Every thing else seems to end up with a sniper shot from a window or a bullet from a crowd. Think of some thing like an old police box (The thing the TARDIS looks like) on two wheels and a bit smaller to fit through door ways.

Does this seem like a good solution to the problem? Stairs are an issue. If the prisoner was not cooperating would he be able to throw his weight around enough to topple the thing?

It seems a bit brutal putting the prisoner in effectively a metal coffin, is this a likely solution in an otherwise reasonably polite and free society?

Comment: Does the prisoner want to live?

Comment: Interesting question @frodoskywalker In this case we will assume the prisoner would rather live than kill him self. He is loyal but not that loyal.

Comment: I should add if given a chance the prisoner will escape and vanish.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add any information requested in comments. Comments are ephemeral and subject to deletion; your question should be the true source of the information needed to answer your question. I would also suggest amending the title to mention the threat of an outside operative shooting the prisoner.

Comment: If the prisoner is rational and wants to live, you put a suicide vest on him (covered by his jacket so no one knows he's wearing it). The suicide vest is triggered by a deadman's switch held by the detective. The pair then walk out of the city. Ensuring the survival of the detective immediately becomes the captive's top priority.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast I really did not see this comment before I answered.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: Is that title better? Couldn't think of better wording off the top of my head. Also included the comments in the main text.

Comment: Your streets do not allow standard cars, but can't other vehicles?

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin: what do you mean by other vehicles? I was going with a segway like thing as its only a bit bigger than a person and reasonably manoeuvrable. I guess you could get a push bike or motorcycle around but it wouldn't offer much/any protection to the prisoner.

Comment: Well you could essentially mount an armoured phone booth on wheels. Add a small motor, *et voilà*.

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin That is sort of what I was thinking of. I've edited the question to include more of a description.

Comment: Does the Big Bad organization have an issue with slaughtering Police to get to one of their members, or do they prefer to get a clean hit on the captured and then evade?

Comment: @Oak I've edited the question to add that "Big Bad Organization" would rather avoid killing the police if it can be helped.

Comment: Stuff him in a hot dog cart and wheel him out.

Comment: [In a bulletproof invisible box](http://www.galactanet.com/comic/view.php?strip=97)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All buildings **must** be accessible by the fire department and emergency services. In cities also accessible for logistics such as maintenance. Residential buildings will be accessible for the vans residents use when moving large furniture.

Just fake a fire, suicide attempt, or a delivery of large furniture and you can use a car just fine. The prisoner can be inside the (bullet proof?) furniture, in a body bag or covered up on a stretcher. Or disguised as a fire fighter with a mask on. Unless there is a detailed plan that leaks, he will be safe enough.

In the unlikely event the building is really physically inaccessible, there is still some method for moving furniture or gaining emergency access already prepared.

You can also dress him in police riot gear and put him in a group of real police officers in the same gear and same general build. Measures against snipers such as large shields or sheets of ballistic cloth exist.

The most important thing really would be moving fast. Moving the person to secure location should be the first thing you do after you arrest them. You should not give anyone time to plan an assassination. This is quite safe unless your intentions leak before you make the move. In which case the person is already dead or missing when you first arrive and no method for moving them is needed. So in a way your question is misleading as the correct solution is to never be in such a situation.

Comment: Darn, I think you are probably correct with this one. I was thinking the area had been originally built pre-cars but they would still have had to get furniture in and out and deal with fires. Meaning there would have been a minimum space between buildings for carts.

Comment: This is where I was going to take my awnser, disguise him to look like a police officer to give the organization the choice of either killing all officers and exposing themselves, or giving up

Comment: + 1 for putting him in police gear and hiding him amongst the mass. Hide a tree in a forest.

Answer (score 3):

Take him to the roof of the tallest building in the area and extract him by helicopter. Depending on how tall the building is relative to surrounding buildings, he might have to lie down to avoid being sniped from an adjacent building before the helicopter turns up.

If the bad guys somehow have line of sight on all available roofs and can therefore snipe the target as soon as he steps outside, I suppose you could have a (fairly powerful) helicopter fly in with an armored box slung beneath it. Position the box on the roof such that the cop and his prisoner can enter it without being exposed to enemy fire--drop it so that the door to the box is extremely close to the roof access door--then fly away with the box hanging below the helicopter.

Presumably the Big Bad Organization is not willing to murder a bunch of cops just to kill the prisoner. If they are willing to kill the cops too, well, I hope there's a secret tunnel system or something like that because your intrepid detective is in serious trouble.

Comment: An aerial extraction, while a lot less tense and dramatic than a street level run to the nearest car, is probably the safest option. I might go for needing a lift due to the clutter on the roof.

Also nice one on not suggesting police strap bombs to people.

Answer (score 0):

If this area of the city has a sewer, just walk him out. Since he's underground, the prisoner doesn't really have anywhere to go. Then it doesn't matter how many snipers are positioned in windows and on rooftops because there's no line of sight to make a shot into the sewer.

If you do an air lift, you run the risk of someone taking out the helicopter, which is what happened in the movie [S.W.A.T.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.W.A.T._(film)) Using the sewer is how they solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use a motorbike.

Get a two-seater with a high back for the passenger and then strap him to the seat. Make sure he can't move (throw his weight around) or it could end badly for you.

And hitting someone on a motorbike with a sniper is rather hard.